# Multiple widgets on a QDockWidget

Tags: c++, layout, widget, qwidget, qdockwidget

I'm making a little app for applying various filters on an image using Qt and C++.

My question is, is it possible to add multiple **widgets** on a **QDockWidget** ?
As i want to add buttons for re-applying the last 5 filters on the dock.

Here is an example of what i want to achieve.

[image: Exemple of what i want to achieve]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible add to multiple `QWidget`s into any `QWidget`.
It looks like you probably want to do something like this:

```
QDockWidget dock(QLatin1String("Last filters"));
QWidget* multiWidget = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
QPushButton* filter1 = new QPushButton(QLatin1String("Filter number 1"));
QPushButton* filter2 = new QPushButton(QLatin1String("Filter number 2"));
QPushButton* filter3 = new QPushButton(QLatin1String("Filter number 3"));
QPushButton* filter4 = new QPushButton(QLatin1String("Filter number 4"));
QPushButton* filter5 = new QPushButton(QLatin1String("Filter number 5"));
QLabel* label = new QLabel(QLatin1String("QPushButtons"));

layout->addWidget(filter1);
layout->addWidget(filter2);
layout->addWidget(filter3);
layout->addWidget(filter4);
layout->addWidget(filter5);
layout->addWidget(label);
multiWidget->setLayout(layout);
dock.setWidget(multiWidget);
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete code for this example so that the example can be built from scratch?

Comment: @AvnerMoshkovitz I'm sorry, but no. That goes against the intention and purpose of http://stackoverflow.com If you have a question about *how* to do something I'd love to help; just ask a question and link me to it. Asking me to do something for you is quite different. This isn't a tutorial site or a prototype library. That said I would like to help. So I'd suggest starting here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html If after attempting you're still struggling with getting something specific going, I'd say you're ready to ask a how question!

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether a layout can be added directly to the dock widget. In this case `multiWidget` would not be required, only `layout`. It seems this is not possible, contrary to other `Widget` derived classes.

Comment: While I think this answer is correct, the proposed method puts an unexpected and maybe unwanted padding around the added widgets. To get rid of this padding, use `layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`.